# Confirming HTTP caching with Fiddler

Tags: caching, fiddler

How can I use Fiddler to confirm that HTTP caching is working? Is there another better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can confirm caching by having a page fetch a resource and note that no request for the resource appeared in Fiddler.  I can't think of a better way to do it.  Works for me.

Answer (score 3):

right click the URL in the fiddler and click properties, you can check the cach info in that popup under "WININET CACHE INFO"

Answer (score 2):

Browse the site through the Fiddler as proxy. In each response details, there's a tab "Caching". This shows useful info about the response headers - e.g. what the different Cache-Control and Expires values mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use the method demonstrated within most caching tutorials - Have a label on the page that displays the current server time. If the value is cached, you will not see it update with subsequent page refreshes until the cache is regenerated.

If your requirement is more complex (you need to use Fiddler), Anthony's suggestion is the one I have used successfully in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler will definitely help with this. You'll either see the server respond with an HTTP 304 response (Not Modified - which tells the client that the cached item is still valid) or for content that has it's web expiry set correctly, you won't see a request at all.

In fact, you'll find Firefox plus FireBug will do this for you too.

Comment: HTTP 302 is only for ETag caching, where the client has to check back with the server and the server returns HTTP 302 (Not Modified) without a body to indicate the client has cached the freshest value.

Comment: Actually, I mistyped when I wrote this response and meant to type 304 (not modified) and not 302 (found). That said, neither 302 or 304 are ETag-only responses, so I'm not sure the comment above makes sense,.

Comment: I shall edit my answer to correctly refer to 304 (not 302)